# Эффект появления/исчезновения в слайдере на javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. У меня есть слайдер где происходит смена слайдов путем смены src картинок. Но переход происходит без плавности, что я бы хотел исправить путем добавления эффекта fadeIn/fadeOt на **javascripte**. Как можно было бы это реализовать?
Вот мой скрипт:

```
function  changeImage(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (targetElement.tagName == 'IMG'){
        document.getElementById('main-img').src = targetElement.getAttribute('src');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 способ:

Тебе нужно всего лишь через js добавлять класс нужной картинке.

Вот css для этих классов:

```
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}


.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

2 способ: 
Используй jQuery и не парься)